# Replace when nil, not false

Tags: ruby

I want to replace a hash' nil values with a certain default:

```
hash = { a: 'populated', b: false, c: nil }
hash.map { |k, v| v || 'REPLACED BECAUSE NIL' }
#=> expected: ["populated", false, "REPLACED BECAUSE NIL"]
#   got:      ["populated", "REPLACED BECAUSE NIL", "REPLACED BECAUSE NIL"]
```

However, the catch is that I DON'T want to overwrite false. I want to keep false, and only overwrite nil.

Can I do this in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`nil?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) method.

```
hash = { a: 'populated', b: false, c: nil }
hash.map { |k, v| v.nil? ? 'REPLACED BECAUSE NIL' : v }
# => ["populated", false, "REPLACED BECAUSE NIL"]
```

As stated in the documentation, only the object `nil` responds `true` to `nil?` so you won't have any issues with falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for nil'ness with `v == nil`.  The Hash class also supports default values with `hash = Hash.new('Something')`:

```
hash = Hash.new 'llama'
hash[:blark]
#=> "llama"
```

Or your way

```
hash = { a: 'populated', b: false, c: nil }
hash.map { |k, v| v == nil ? 'REPLACED BECAUSE NIL' : v }
```